# Why does the tail of a Fréchet distribution decay as a power law?

Tags: distributions, convergence, kurtosis, power-law

The [Fréchet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution): $$\Phi_\alpha(x)=\begin{cases}0,\; x\leq 0\\e^{-x^{-\alpha}},\; x>0\end{cases}$$

shows a power law decay at the tail (survival):

$$1- \Phi_\alpha(x) = 1 -e^{-x^{-\alpha}}\sim x^{-\alpha}, \; x \to \infty$$

How can I prove this? I suppose it is done with a Taylor series (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $f$ and $g$ are *asymptotically equal* (as $x$ approaches infinity), denoted by

$$ f(x) \sim g (x) \; \; (x\rightarrow \infty),$$ if

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1. $$

In your case,  we have ($\alpha >0$)

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-e^{-x^{-\alpha}}}{x^{-\alpha}} \stackrel{y=x^{-\alpha}}{=}\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-e^{-y}}{y} \stackrel{L'Hospital}{=} \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{-y}}{1} = 1 $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I will accept it. I posted a related entry: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/529628/311006